# Access Javascript confirm result from classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have often used something along the following lines in Classic ASP:

```
Response.Write "<script type=""text/javascript"">alert('Hello world')</script>"
```

but how would I do something similar for Javascript's confirm statement and return the result to my vb to interrogate the result?

```
Response.Write "<script type=""text/javascript"">confirm('Do you want to continue?')</script>"
```

is clearly not enough. I need to assign the result to a variable if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this directly. You will have to use AJAX to send the user response to the server then possibly parse the response from the server in the client side code.

Answer (score 1):

I would use window prompt() method. Here is an example from W3 schools:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
    if (person != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have used the above example from W3 to capture input, but to take value and submit to server:

```
document.getElementById("demo").value=
        person
document.submit()
```